# AngularJS Select element set the selected index

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, default, selectedindex

So i'm using angular and this is my select html:

```
<select id="date" ng-model="selectedDay" ng-change="setDate()" >
    <option>another option</option>
    <option>an option</option>
</select>
```

this is in my controller:

```
$scope.selectedDay;
document.getElementById("date").selectedIndex = "0";
```

**The result:** Three options: one blank (which is default selected) and then the two options I made in html

What the hell? why isn't the default when i open the view "another option"

Comment: Go with `ngOptions` when you use `select` in AngularJS https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, always check the official documentation. AngularJs is well documented.

Secondly, do not use `document.getElementById ("date") selectedIndex = "0"`  - that's javascript. Avoid using pure Javascript when an Angular function is available.

Documentation:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

Comment: Thank you! ng-selected="selectedOption" in controller: selectedOption = "another option" did the trick!