# document getelementbyid options selectedindex in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This works in perfect javascript

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex = "0"

<select class="selectpicker" id="mySelect">
    <option>English &nbsp;</option>
    <option>Español &nbsp;</option>
</select>
```

How do you do this same but in Angularjs

```
app.controller("BodyController",function($scope){
/****************codeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee*/
});
```

Comment: You would use `ngOptions` with your select and set the `ngModel` to the option you want selected. And you can use the exact same code (it'd just be the complete wrong way of doing it in Angular, but it would work... because Angular is JavaScript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS Select element set the selected index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217067/angularjs-select-element-set-the-selected-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add the [`ng-model`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) attribute to the *select* tag, and then set the value of the matching variable in the *scope* (corresponding to the scope set in the controller). See the example below - bear in mind that `value` attribute were added to the options. And like **tymeJV** mentioned, [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) would typically be used in an angular application to set the *option* nodes inside the *select* tag (see the second example below).

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller("BodyController",function($scope){
  //set the model value to 'en', so the select list will select the option with value=='en'
  $scope.lang = 'en';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="BodyController">
<select class="selectpicker" id="mySelect" ng-model="lang">
    <option value="en">English &nbsp;</option>
    <option value="es">Español &nbsp;</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Using [*ngOptions*](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions):

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller("BodyController",function($scope){
  //set the model value to 'en', so the select list will select the option with value=='en'
  $scope.lang = {name: 'English', id: 'en'};
  $scope.langs = [
      {name: 'English', id: 'en'},
      {name: 'Español', id: 'es'}
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="BodyController">
<select class="selectpicker" id="mySelect" ng-model="lang" ng-options="lang.name for lang in langs track by lang.id">
</select>
</div>
```